# How to sample a non-periodic signal using an Arduino Due?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, embedded, dsp

Input: fig(1)

[image]

/* graph plot
input signal freq :3KHZ
*/

Here is my code :

```
#define SAMPLES 1024
#define SAMPLING_FREQUENCY 20000 //HZ

unsigned int sampling_period_us;
unsigned long microseconds;

double rawData[SAMPLES];
//bool INTR_FLAG=0;

void setup(){

  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(A0 , INPUT);
  pinMode(DAC0 , OUTPUT);
  analogReadResolution(12);
  analogWriteResolution(12);


}


void loop(){
  //ok
 /*int a=analogRead(A0);
  Serial.println(a);
  analogWrite(DAC0,a);
  delay(100); */  


       sampling_period_us = round(1000000 *(1.0/SAMPLING_FREQUENCY));

  for(int i=0 ; i<SAMPLES ;i++){

      microseconds =micros();

      rawData[i]=analogRead(A0);
      Serial.println(rawData[i]);

      while(micros() < (microseconds + sampling_period_us)){
        
      }   
  }
  
for(int i=0 ; i<SAMPLES ;i++){
  
  analogWrite(DAC0,rawData[i]);
  //Serial.println(rawData[i]);
  
}  
    
}
```

output on arduino serial port : fig2

[image]

DAC0 waveform on CRO

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of `dac0` and `rawData[]` in the code? The rawData loop may be taking a lot of time to execute.

Comment: first I take a sample value of the signal after that find the peak value of the signal.

Comment: DAC0  just redraw the signal from rawdata . just for cross checking. if I'm wrong please let me know

Comment: Maybe Move the `Serial.println` outside the sample reading loop? Does that function ensure that the previous data was fully transmitted before next transmission??? In some micro controllers, the serial data buffer is only one or two byte long. Will successive `println` commands overwrite the buffer. I am not talking about rawData when I say buffer, but the register in the microcontroller which holds serial data. The baud rate 9600 is much less than sampling frequency 20kHz. Buffer may be getting overwritten???

Comment: Additionally consider increasing your Serial baudrate to something faster than 9600, making the data transfer faster

Comment: In the graph with blue and red lines, which line is DAC0? Is DAC0 actual analogue signal or a  PWM signal? If PWM, are you low pass filtering before viewing in scope?

Comment: red -DAC0(analog signal)

Comment: I tried with 115200 baud rate ---no change in result

Comment: There is no timing control in the analogWrite loop. It will write successive values very very quickly. You may want to implement the time delay code in that loop also. If PWM, check what is the PWM frequency. It should be much bigger than the analog write frequent.

Comment: analog pin A0 is used. I'm taking a sample after fixed interval..should I increase the time interval?

Comment: no timing control means?

Comment: #define SAM 1024
#define SAM_FREQ 9000 
unsigned int sampling_period_us;
unsigned long microseconds;
double rawData[SAM];
void setup(){ Serial.begin(115200);
pinMode(A0 , INPUT);
pinMode(DAC0 , OUTPUT);
analogReadResolution(12);
analogWriteResolution(12); sampling_period_us = round(1000000 *(1.0/SAM_FREQ));
 for(int i=0 ; i<SAM ;i++){
  microseconds =micros();
 rawData[i]=analogRead(A0);
 Serial.println(rawData[i]);
while(micros() < (microseconds + sampling_period_us)){        
 }     }  
for(int i=0 ; i<SAMPLES ;i++){ analogWrite(DAC0,rawData[i]);  }  }
void loop(){}

Comment: The currently posted answer (@JRE) gives some good points to follow. If you are planning to still salvage the current code, I would suggest as next the debugging setup, to remove the `Serial.begin` and `Serial.println` lines to see if that is slowing down your code. You will have to then debug using only the DAC output. You can also add timing control to the `analogWrite` loop. [Suggested modification](https://pastebin.com/5aA66uiS).

Answer (score 3):

1. The Arduino [analogRead](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogread/) takes 100 microseconds per read.  That limits you to a sampling rate under 10kHz.  You will **never** reach your intended 20kHz sampling rate.
2. The Serial.println takes time.  Since you are using it in your sampling loop, it makes the time between samples longer. You will **never** reach the Arduino's theoretical 10kHz sampling rate.
3. The Due has a real analog output on DAC0 and DAC1, so you should be able to get a real signal out.  It can write about every 4 microseconds when using the analogwrite method.  That's about 10 times faster than the sampling rate of 20kHz that you were aiming for, and a great deal faster than you are really sampling.  Whatever you put out will be compressed in time compared to the original signal.
4. The signal you are looking at has pulses that are about .3 milliseconds long.  That's a frequency over 3kHz.   To sample it, you'll need well over 6000 samples per second.  Even if you were sampling at the full 10kHz the Arduino is capable of, it would just barely be able to resolve your signal.  It would look pretty much like a bunch of random wiggles around 3 or 4 samples wide.
5. Your signal seems to be transient.  It comes and then goes away.  Your Arduino program doesn't seem to wait for the signal to start (it has no trigger) so it is entirely possible that it never "sees" the signal at all.  It could be off doing DAC0 output every time your interesting signal occurs.

The Due is only marginally capable of what you want from it, and your programming technique is pushing the real performance even further from the meager reality.  Even if you got things perfect, you wouldn't be happy with the results.

You need to read and write the ports directly (bypassing the Arduino functions) and you need to use timers and interrupts instead of delays to time your sampling and play back. Reading and writing directly gets you **much** faster read and write response - you can actually read fast enough for what you need.  Using a timer driven interrupt to do your sampling means that the sampling rate is reliable and steady.

You might also switch to a faster, more capable microprocessor.  It won't be as convenient as the Arduino, but you'll have a better chance of accurately sampling your signal.

---

Just FYI:

The signal trace you showed did **not** come from a CRO. A CRO would be a "cathode ray oscilloscope."  That refers to the huge vacuum tube display found in old fashioned oscilloscopes.

Your plot appears to come from a program on a PC reading from one of the headless USB oscilloscopes that are commonly (and cheaply) available.

For reference, this is a cathode ray oscilloscope:

[image]

The cathode ray tube is the green display.  It is only about 12 cm across, so the display area isn't huge.  The tube itself is over 30 cm long, though, the whole tube is slightly monstrous.

That's my oscilloscope.  Big, heavy cantankerous, hot.